# Unable to parse .docx or .xlsx file using apache tika -1.6. Jarfiles are getting loaded, but it is not parsing

Tags: parsing, indexing, solr, apache-tika

The last line is returning blank value.

```
    Parser _autoParser = new AutoDetectParser();
    ContentHandler textHandler = new BodyContentHandler(-1);

    PDFParserConfig pdfConfig = new PDFParserConfig();
    pdfConfig.setExtractInlineImages(true);
    System.out.println("inside Tika");
    Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
    ParseContext contextParse = new ParseContext();

    contextParse.set(PDFParserConfig.class, pdfConfig);
    contextParse.set(Parser.class, _autoParser);
    InputStream input = new FileInputStream(fLoc);
    System.out.println("trying to read the file content");
    _autoParser.parse(input, textHandler, metadata, contextParse);
```

Comment: I am using Tika-server1.6.jar . error shows :

Comment: Why are you using such an old version of Apache Tika? What happens when you upgrade?

Comment: problem persists with Apache tika server 1.18 also . infact other dependencies are coming here.

Comment: What happens when you follow https://wiki.apache.org/tika/Troubleshooting%20Tika ?

Comment: ok this issue is fixed. the problem is i added some additional jar files which was causing incompatibility.